# Replace a DIV inside a contact form with another DIV in PHP

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I've tried different solutions in Stackoverflow but I can't find one that works with the code I have.

I’m working on a contact form where the DIV that has the textfields and the labels should be replaced by another one containing a thank you message.

So far I've gotten the thank you message to appear, but the DIV with the contact data is not disappearing. I used the same name for the one that has the fields and the DIV of the thank you message.

Everything is in the same file called “pregunta.php”

If it’s possible, I would like the DIV disappear and not the full form.

I do not know much about PHP or Javascript codes.

Here is the part in PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['send_message'])){
    $errors = array(); // declaramos un array para almacenar los errores
        if($_POST['sender_name'] == ''){
            $errors[1] = '<span class="error">*Ingrese su nombre</span>';
            $mail_sent = false;
        }else if($_POST['sender_email'] == ''){
            $errors[2] = '<span class="error">*Ingrese un email correcto</span>';
            $mail_sent = false;
        }else if($_POST['sender_phone'] == ''){
            $errors[3] = '<span class="error">*Ingrese un teléfono</span>';
            $mail_sent = false;
        }else if($_POST['sender_empresa'] == ''){
            $errors[4] = '<span class="error">*Nombre de la empresa para la que trabaja</span>';
            $mail_sent = false;
        }else if($_POST['sender_message'] == ''){
            $errors[5] = '<span class="error">*Escriba un mensaje</span>';
            $mail_sent = false;
        }
        else{//si todo esta ok envia email

            $name = $_POST['sender_name'];
            $mail_from = $_POST['sender_email'];
            $phone = $_POST['sender_phone'];
            $empresa = $_POST['sender_empresa'];
            $message = $_POST['sender_message'];

            // Encabezados del mensaje
            $headers = 'From: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";

            // Construct email body
            $body_message = '///////////DATOS PERSONALES'."\r\n";
            $body_message .= "\r\n";
            $body_message .= 'De: ' . $name . "\r\n";
            $body_message .= 'Correo: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";
            $body_message .= 'Teléfono: ' . $phone . "\r\n";
            $body_message .= 'Empresa: ' . $empresa . "\r\n";
            $body_message .= 'Mensaje: ' . $message . "\r\n";
            $body_message .= "\r\n";


        if(mail("giselle@intex-mkt.com",'Mensaje de página',$body_message,$headers))
        {           
          $result = // This is the DIV with the Thank You Message
         '<div id="datos">
           <center><img src="img/avion.png" alt="Mensaje enviado" style="text-align:center;"/></center>
            <p style="text-align:center; font-size:12px; color:#FFF;">¡Gracias!<br/> Nos comunicaremos contigo en cuanto tengamos los resultados de tu búsqueda</p>

            <div class="botones">
                <a href="cotiza.php"><input type="submit" class="boton1" name="regresa_cotiza" value="&laquo;Regresar"></a> <a href="index.php"><input type="submit" class="boton2" name="ir_inicio" value="Ir a inicio &raquo;" ></a>
            </div><!-- Fin botones -->
          </div><!-- Fin datos-->';

          $_POST['sender_name'] = '';
          $_POST['sender_email'] = '';
          $_POST['sender_phone'] = '';
          $_POST['sender_empresa'] = '';
          $_POST['sender_message'] = '';
        } 
        else 
        { $result = '<div class="result_fail">Hubo un error al enviar el mensaje</div>'; }
        }
    }
        ?>
```

Here is the contact form:

```
<form class="contacto" action="pregunta.php" method="POST">
<?php echo $result ?>
                <div id="datos">
                <table width="auto" align="center" >
                <tr>
                <td>
                <form class="contacto" action="pregunta.php" method="POST">
                    <p style="padding-left:0px; font-size:11px;"><i>*Campos obligatorios</i></p>
                     <br/>
                    <div class="campo" style="margin-left:-10px;"><label for="field_name"><p>Nombre* </label><input type="text" id="field_name" class="textfield" name="sender_name" value='<?php echo $_POST['sender_name']; ?>'></p></div><!-- Fin class campo --><?php echo $errors[1]; ?>
                    <br/>    
                    <div class="campo" style="margin-left:-10px;"><label for="field_email"><p>Correo* </label>
                    <input type="text" id="field_email" class="textfield" name="sender_email" value='<?php echo $_POST['sender_email']; ?>'></p></div><!-- Fin class campo --><?php echo $errors[2]; ?>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="campo" style="margin-left:-10px;"><label for="field_phone"><p>Teléfono* </label>
                    <input type="text" id="field_phone" class="textfield" name="sender_phone" value='<?php echo $_POST['sender_phone']; ?>' style="margin-top:-12px;"></p></div><!-- Fin class campo --><?php echo $errors[3]; ?>
                    <br/>    
                    <div class="campo" style="margin-left:-10px;"><label for="field_phone"><p>Empresa* </label>
                    <input type="text" id="field_empresa" class="textfield" name="sender_empresa" value='<?php echo $_POST['sender_empresa']; ?>' style="margin-top:-12px;"></p></div><!-- Fin class campo --><?php echo $errors[4]; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="campo"><label for="field_message"><p style="margin-left:10px;">Mensaje* </label><br /><br />
                    <textarea id="field_message" rows="6" class="field_mensaje" name="sender_message"><?php echo $_POST['sender_message']; ?></textarea></p></div><!-- Fin class campo --><?php echo $errors[5]; ?>   
                </td>
                <tr/>
                </table>
                    <input type="submit" class="boton" name="send_message" value="Enviar">
                </form>

            </div><!-- Fin datos -->
```

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is best accomplished with AJAX or a redirection after a completed form submit to a Thank You page. Why can't you do something like that?

Comment: Well, is actually something I can't do, the client wants the form to work this way. You think there is no way to make it work with this code?

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna look for a tutorial for AJAX, do you know a good one I can use? I would appreciate it

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer complete if it helped...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make any sense what you need to do.... but something you could do is incorporate Javascript/jQuery to submit the form via AJAX and when it's successfully sent, replace the HTML with your thank you message. But again, that can't be done with pure PHP as it's a server side language.

You could also maybe try to set a unique Cookie once a form is submitted and when your page is refreshed, check for the cookie. If it exists, show your thank you message in place of your text fields...That's seriously sloppy and and unprofessional technique though.

**Update** [Check out this article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form). It does exactly what you want to do using AJAX, PHP & jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You are totally over-complicating and using very excessive and unnecessary code that should have been coded via AJAX/Javascript.

My [strong] suggestion is to take an hour or two, go to YouTube, and search "ajax tutorial", and begin with lesson 1)... Refresh your JS skills, and code it using the industry Best Practices, meaning JS/AJAX), rather than PHP.

I also recommend learning AJAX via jQuery as the means to perform any AJAX calls - it's much simpler.

TRUST ME...

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I'll start working on my JS skills.